# Solving $x+yy' =3y^2y'\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Please solve this differential equation
>
> $$x+yy' =3y^2y'\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

I tried to use $v=x^2+y^2$, but I'm stuck after few lines.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

You were close.

After rendering $v=x^2+y^2$ you have

$v'/2=3\sqrt{v}y^2y'$

Divide by $\sqrt{v}$, and then

$v'/(2\sqrt{v})=3y^2y'$

Converting the derivatives to differentials by multiplying by $dx$ then gives

$dv/(2\sqrt{v})=3y^2dy$

which is easy to integrate. Remember to include the constant of integration. To get a relation between $x$ and $y$, put back $v=x^2+y^2$ after doing the integration.

Comment: I'm afraid it's wrong.. v'/2= 3sqrt(v)* y^2 * y' i guess...

Comment: Missed the square root due to poor formatting in the q.